# Converting string to real or double

Tags: fortran90

In f90 I need to encode a 30 character string as real/double and recover it in a different place from this real/double number. How to do that?
Thanks,
Mark

Comment: What coding scheme do you propose to use ?  A 30 character string probably occupies 240-bits and a double-precision real number has 64-bits.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use doubles, I'd use integers. Specifically an *array* of integers. And the intrinsic functions `ichar` and `achar` that convert a character to its ASCII equivalent and back (respectively).

You could whip this up easily:

```
program string_to_int
   implicit none
   integer :: mystring_int(30), i
   character(len=30) :: mystring

   mystring = "Fortran is the best language!!"
   do i=1,30
      mystring_int(i) = ichar(mystring(i:i))
   enddo
   print *,mystring_int

   call read_back_int(mystring_int)
 contains
   subroutine read_back_int(cvar)
     integer, intent(in) :: cvar(:)
     character(len=size(cvar)) :: substring
     integer :: i
     do i=1,size(cvar)
        substring(i:i) = achar(cvar(i))
     enddo
     print *,substring

   end subroutine read_back_int

end program string_to_int
```

Using the (intrinsic) function `sizeof`, it shows me that the character string is 30 bytes while integer array is 120 bytes. If you *really* want to use double, then replacing `integer` with `real(kind=c_double)` (which requires the `iso_c_binding` module) would do the trick too.